# VBA click HTML button without a name?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am attempting to click this login button on a website using VBA, here is the HTML for the button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="submitForm();">
```

I have already got it to the point where it enters my username and password as those fields had names but I am unable to get it to click this button as it does not have a name. I have been searching and either I do not know what I am looking for or this must not be that common of an issue. Here is my latest attempt:

```
objIE.document.getElementsByName("Login")(0).Click
```

Thanks!

Comment: objIE.document.getElementsByName("Login")[0].click();

Comment: @DarthMoon Syntax error my friend, this is run within Excel using VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you state: there is no `name` attribute in the HTML for the element you show. You can use an `attribute = value` CSS selector to target the attributes that are present:

```
objIE.document.querySelector("[onclick='submitForm();']").click
```

Same idea means

```
objIE.document.querySelector("[value=Login]").click
```

Or even

```
objIE.document.querySelector("[type=submit]").click
```

Finally, you may be able to submit the form direct with

```
objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).submit
```

If there is more than one element that can be matched on the attribute selector then use `.querySelectorAll` to retrieve them all and index into the returned nodeList to get the right one e.g.

```
objIE.document.querySelectorAll("[type=submit]").item(1).click
```

Where 1 in the above would be the second matched. 2 would be the third etc.

Comment: This worked perfectly and your answer provided multiple different ways to accomplish the task. I appreciate you giving multiple variances, I am sure this answer will help many in the future. Thanks!